# Stop thread after sometime

Tags: android

I am writing a game in which after a specified amount of time a thread must be stopped.The user has failed to complete a particular level.I am using a thread.How do i stop this thread after a specified amount of time and display another view.How do i do this.The following code delays the launching of the thread by timelimit.

```
Thread t = ... t.join(timelimit); 
if (t.isAlive) 
t.interrupt();
```

How do i run the thread and close it after a period of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your working thread

```
public class Worker extends Thread {
    private boolean isRunning = true;
    public void run() {
        while (isRunning) {
            /* do your stuff here*/
        }
    }

    public void stopWorker() {
         isRunning = false;
    }
}
```

Your stopping thread

```
public class Stopper extends Thread {
    private Worker worker;
    public void Stopper(Worker w) {
        worker = w;
    }

    public void run() {
        // wait until your timeout expires
        worker.stopWorker();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you should declare your thread with something like this

```
public class GameLoopThread extends Thread{
private boolean running = false;

public void setRunning(boolean run){
    running = run;
}

@Override
public void run(){
    while(running){

    }
}
}
```

This is the safer way, In order to stop you should set the running variable to false. Otherwise If you stop the thead you will get an android exception .

Comment: in this case running should be volatile (or you need to synchonize access to it)

Answer (score 1):

I prefer interrupting the Thread from outside and checking interrupted state in short intervals:

```
try {
    while (!Thread.currentThread.interrupted()) {
        doSth();
    }
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // finished
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use below code is run after given specified time.

```
 Handler handler = new Handler();
    handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            // after this is rung               
        }
    }, 5000);
```